# Given a JSON object with a $schema property, how do I validate it without providing the schema again?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have an [`.ndjson`](http://ndjson.org/) file with a bunch of JSON objects. Each object has a `$schema` property pointing to a file with a [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/) defining the validation rules for that object. (If it helps, we can assume that I have a bunch of files instead of a `.ndjson` file - splitting it into multiple files is easy.)

I've looked around for a way to validate the JSON objects against the referenced `$schema`s, but all validators I can find require me to specify not only the object but also the schema explicitly.

For example:

- [`jsonschema` (Python)](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)
- [`fastjsonschema` (Python)](https://horejsek.github.io/python-fastjsonschema/)
- [`pajv` (Node/Commandline)](https://github.com/json-schema-everywhere/pajv)

all require me to specify the schema as input.

Is there a validator that will read the `$schema` property instead of requiring me to provide the schema explicitly?

Comment: Have you considered running it in a loop and providing the schema as required? `$schema` doesn't actually define a schema to use, but is actually an identifier for the JSON Schema dialect a schema is using. We explicitly do not define using the `$schema` keyword in an instance, only ever in a Schema.

Comment: If you'd like to discuss, I'm happy to do so on our friendly Slack server (link on the json schema site). As an aside, I'd love to hear how you're using JSON Schema at Spotify.

Comment: @Relequestual: Interesting! For the automated validation when writing data, we actually do provide the schema to the validators in a loop. The problem I'm trying to solve now is that the schema might change over time, and currently, one has to know what schema was valid at the time of writing a specific instance; I want to make the instances "self-documenting" - even if they link to other places, one should ideally not need to know anything not visible in the instance to know how to interpret and validate it at some later time.

Comment: Sure, you can totally add `$schema` to your instance JSON, but you have to consider it would be non-standard and you can't expect to find tooling to support that approach.

Comment: Cool. I guess I didn't realize `$schema` didn't apply to instances - I've seen enough samples of JSON files that specify a schema (mainly things like config files for dev tooling, where the tooling uses the schema to build auto-complete options etc) that I just assumed it was a standards-compliant thing. Today I learned!

Comment: We get that a LOT. VSCode documents this fact here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json#_mapping-in-the-json